# I just asked a question, but it hasn't appeared on the list.

Tags: support, status-norepro, asking-questions

I just asked this question: [GND difference between CAN nodes?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9390/gnd-difference-between-can-nodes) but it hasn't appeared on the list of questions, even after 25 minutes. Nor does it appear if I search for its tags.

However it is listed on my home page.

Did I ask it wrong?

Comment: Did you forget your sacrifice to the lord of the servers this morning, hmm?

Comment: Is either PIC or CAN (the tags applied to the question) in your ignored tags list?

Comment: Nope. I don't think I have an ignore list.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this. I see the questions on the home page and the 'Questions' page. It has 60+ views so *other* users are seeing it, too.

Make sure you are looking at a page where the question is *supposed* to appear. Check the tabs on the top of the listing. You won't see your question on, for example, the `featured` tab (i.e. your question does not have a bounty).

Comment: It did finally appear. It took about 40 minutes. Perhaps there was some maintenance happening in the server or something?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check (this happened to me!) is that a tag you used in your question is not in your ignored tags list. The question won't appear if you have ignored tag questions set to not appear at all in your preferences.

*(This happened to me on SO because I was ignoring Twitter tags but eventually needed to develop an app that used the Twitter API.)*